# Responsive property does not work on react-slick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, slider

I want to change `sliderToShow` property on small devices but the `responsive` property does not work.

```
let settings_3 = {
  dots: false,
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
  slidesToShow: 3,

  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 600,
    settings_3: {
      slidesToShow: 2,
      slidesToScroll: 2,
      initialSlide: 2
    }
  }]
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't add the full code its so long, but my problem is here. I don't have any errors

Comment: @John Well, this is obviously not enough information for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `settings_3` to `settings` inside the `responsive[]`. There is no `settings_3` property in slick:

```js
class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let settings_3 = {
      dots: false,
      autoplay: false,
      autoplaySpeed: 3000,
      slidesToShow: 3,

      responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 2,
          initialSlide: 2
        }
      }]
    };
    return (
      <Slider {...settings_3}>
        <div>
          <h3>1</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>2</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>3</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>4</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>5</h3>
        </div>
        <div>
          <h3>6</h3>
        </div>
      </Slider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <SimpleSlider/> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
#root{
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-slick/0.13.1/react-slick.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: The name doesn't matter, I am writing react not jQuery sorry

Comment: @John, are you using `react-slick`?

Comment: react-slick yes

Comment: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/656
here I found that not only I have that problem but cants resolve.

Comment: @John, I've updated my answer with the React.js version. Seems to be working after changing `settings_3` to `settings`. Resize the window and check. Also, it may be an issue with the `react-slick` version. Just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Use bottom line approach. Start from the smallest one.

```
responsive: [
{
  breakpoint: 900,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 1150,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,
  },
},
{
  breakpoint: 1300,
  settings: {
    slidesToShow: 4,
  },
},
```

],

Answer (score 0):

Just in case there is anyone out there who runs into the same problem as me: if you have a function based component, try changing this to a class based component instead. After trying this the responsive property worked perfectly for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
export const Premier = () => {
    const settings = {
        infinite : true,
        slidesToShow : 5,
        slidesToScroll : 2,
        InitalSlide : 0,

        responsive : [{
            breakpoint : 600,
            settings :{
                slidesToShow: 2,
                slidesToScroll:1,
                autoplay : true,
                infinite :true,
            }
        }],
        responsive : [{
            breakpoint : 1000,
            settings :{
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll:2,
                autoplay : true,
                infinite :true,
            }
        }]
    };
}
```